# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working in AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jersey, cors

I'm trying to consume my (CORS compatible) RESTful service

```
@Path("/greeting")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response greeting() {

    String result = "{\"id\":1,\"content\":\"Hello, World!\"}";

    return Response.ok() //200
            .entity(result)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .build();
}
```

from my AngularJS application.

```
function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.dashboard = "ESCO Dashboard";


    console.log('start');

    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/NobelGrid/api/users/greeting'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('success');
        $scope.greeting = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('error');
    });


    console.log('end');

}
```

but I have this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/NobelGrid/api/users/greeting. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

Using Console Network of Chrome this seems true cause the Response Header is:

[image]

Anyway accessing to the REST service from the browser and not from the Angular app, the header is correct

[image]

I also tried this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

with their RESTful service (also CORS compatible, they said), but the result is the same.

ps: I'm using WebStorm as IDE.

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

Writing this handler at server-side:

```
@Path("/greeting")
@OPTIONS
@Produces("application/json")
public Response greetingOPT() {


    return Response.status(200) //200
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia,Authorization")
            .build();
}
```

it works. At the beginning it gives to me another error:

> Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight [..]

but adding `Authorization` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` of the GET and POST resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error message:

> Response to preflight request

Look at the Network log:

> Request Method: OPTIONS

Look at your API:

> @GET

You need to write a handler for [the preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) before the browser will make the GET request to the handler you have written.

Comment: Hi @Quentin! I didn't understand well (sorry me): I have to write an handler for OPTIONS at server side? Or I have to make some things at client side? Thanks a lot

Comment: You have to write a handler for OPTIONS on your server (or change the request so it doesn't need a preflight check (the specifics of which are described at the other end of the link in the answer)).

Comment: Thanks #Quentin! Please Can you see my UPDATE?